# Why do my RestTemple not connect to server?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, resttemplate

I am working with Springboot and Java 8

I have following url, that works pretty fine with postman:

"http://localhost:8888/gc/goods/getAll"

Now I have tried to write an automated test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GCGoodControllerTest 
{
    @Test
    public void getAllGoodsRequest()
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Object test = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8888/gc/goods/getAll", Object.class);
    }
}
```

While Postman gives me all data back, I get following error from my test:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://localhost:8888/gc/goods/getAll": Connection
>   refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect

How do I request the Data correctly during testing?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace here?

Comment: thank you for your time, but @pcoates already answered the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your server is not up and running on port 8888 when your automated test runs. If you need the test to start your embedded server you need to annotate the test class with something like

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following annotations on your test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) tells JUnit to run using the Spring boot.
@SpringBootTest will load the application.properties and all other spring boot stuff you need.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but that is already there. I have updated my post. Sorry, that I did not metioned it before.